# Change / correct desktop to display mapping

Tags: display, desktop

I have a Mac Book laptop with Mojave. I use two desks (in different location) each having two Dell monitors that I connect via display port to the laptop.

It works well, however when I switch between my desks the desktop are mapped to different monitors. The windows and icons that were on my left monitor at my other desk are now on the right monitor, conversely the windows and icons that were on the right monitor are now on the left one.

Note that the display arrangement is correct, I can move my mouse from one screen to another in the same way that they are physically set (which is the same at both location).

Hence my question: how do I fix the desktop (which contains windows and icons) to screens to have the window placed in the same way regardless where I work?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Have you checking under System Preferences → Displays and verified that the display arrangement and the primary display (one containing the Menu bar) are set up consistently for both the external displays?

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome Nimesh. Yes the display arrangement is similar for both set of external display. In each case the primary display is set to the laptop. If you count the laptop I have 3 display: the laptop, and 2 external monitors. It is the external monitor which are switched from one location to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks which desktop is map to which screen depends on the port the screen is connected to. The (retro) Mac Book pro that I have has two display ports. I must be consistently inverting in which port I input the cables from one location to the other.